# What format should be used for the news_from_date attributre?

Tags: import, magmi

Adding a date to the news_from_date to a new product using the calendar returns to this format: dd/mm/yyyy

but if I mass import (via magmi) a DB the value in magento has been changed to something like "11/30/00-1" which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saving a product, all dates attributes are processed before saving. They are converted from the format corresponding to your admin locale to the standard mysql format (YYYY-mm-dd).
You can try to supply your import with the dates in this format.
For example: June 25th 2013 will be `2013-06-25`

Comment: Hi Marius! with the dash or backslash like YYYY/MM/DD ?

Comment: I would say with a dash. But if it doesn't work, try with a slash.

Comment: dash was good ;)

Comment: @Marius awesome.this I was looking for.you're Magento Jedi :)

Comment: Got to add, it's really misleading of Magento that the product export had the format yyyy/mm/dd. The moment I saw this and changed the import to a dash it worked perfectly. thanks for the post!